# Including H files in other programs x

Tags: c++, include, scope, header-files, include-path

For class I made a struct called time and the h.which looked something like this

```
struct Time{
    Time() : hours(0),minutes(0),seconds(0),ticks(0){}
    int hours, minutes, seconds, ticks;
};

Time convert (clock_t t, Time &time);
std::string hmst(Time &time);
std::string hmst(clock_t t);
```

Later our teacher had us make another program which used the same code in this program. Rather than writing it over i included. First question is this a legitimate #include (assuming the path is correct)

```
#include "../p*/*r*/0*/*s/02*/time.h"
```

Second question I need to use the convert function in the program im currently working on. How would i go about doing this? would i use the scope resolution operator as follows

```
timeobeject=Time::convert(t,time);
```

or like this

```
timeobject=convert(t,time);
```

Comment: To better adjust to the moving of header files or source files, don't put paths in the `#include` statement.  Supply the paths as search directories to the compiler (-I) or to the build system / IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First question is this a legitimate #include (assuming the path is correct)
>
> #include "../p*/*r*/0*/*s/02*/time.h"

Yes. But remember to compile the implementation file of it as well with the current project. Or you can link directly to the object file.

> timeobeject=Time::convert(t,time);

Wrong. `convert` function isn't enclosed in any namespace. You have to directly call it like -

```
timeobeject=convert(t,time);
```